# Postgres JDBC driver not returning error line number as shown in PGAdmin

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgadmin-4

Postgres JDBC driver not returning the exact error line number as shown in PGAdmin. When I run the below program :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String query = "SELECT table_name, table_type\n" +
      "  FROM information_schema.tabls\n" +
      " WHERE table_schema='public'\n" +
      "   AND table_type in ('BASE TABLE','VIEW') ORDER BY table_type, table_name;";

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "postgres")) {

      System.out.println("Connected to PostgreSQL database!");
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.printf("%-30.30s  %-30.30s%n", resultSet.getString("table_name"), resultSet.getString("table_type"));
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error :

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "information_schema.tabls" does not exist
  Position: 38
```

But when I run the same query on pgadmin4, I receive the following error :

```
    ERROR:  relation "information_schema.tabls" does not exist
LINE 2:   FROM information_schema.tabls
               ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 38
```

I want the line number in java program as well. How can I get it?

Comment: Well you get the position inside the query, you need to calculate the line number yourself inside your Java program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PGAdmin4 is a node.js backend that uses Python driver `psycopg2`. This driver is nothing more than a wrapper for C driver named `libpq`, created by the PostgreSQL team.

JDBC driver communicates with database and uses responses received from the server. `org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl#receiveNoticeResponse` private method  responsible for parsing server errors and it just creates new `org.postgresql.util.ServerErrorMessage` instance. So, the response given by the server is equal to the response shown by the JDBC driver.

But as for `libpq`, messages received from the server, and shown on client-side aren't the same. There is `reportErrorPosition` method in `libpq` sources exactly for adding line information. Here is [reference for reportErrorPosition sources](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/272d82ec6febb97ab25fd7c67e9c84f4660b16ac/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-protocol3.c#L1122) for PostgreSQL 13.3. Here is [place where LINE: x is added](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/272d82ec6febb97ab25fd7c67e9c84f4660b16ac/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-protocol3.c#L1303) to the client error.

## Summary

You need to calculate the line number by yourself when using the JDBC driver. Or use C library which does it for you.